# makefile error 2 in ubuntu command

Tags: php, mysql, makefile, ubuntu-12.04, lighttpd

I am trying to building an app from ubuntu 12.04 terminal from home directory. I am using lighttpd, php and mysql in my ubuntu. But The building aborting when it trying to create sql .

There is a makefile. Building aborting when it tries to make this function.

```
.PHONY: check
check: nocheck conf.cat
    $(MAKE) data/panel.sqlmeta.ser
    bin/prep.sh sqlcheck
```

Here is the function of sqlcheck in prep.sh

```
function f_sqlcheck {
  cmd $PHP bin/sqlcheck.php -add -all
}
```

The error in the terminal:

```
..................
............
CREATE TABLE `color`(

`name` VARCHAR(255),

`color` CHAR(6),

`id` INT AUTO_INCREMENT,

PRIMARY KEY(`id`))
.............

abort
make: *** [check] Error 2
```

Any idea how to solve this? I also want to mention that the folder is in my home directory with symlink to /var/www/ and I am executing all the command via sudo.

and also in conf.cat file for this app I edited mysql user as root and provide root password and database name..

Comment: What is `.............` before `abort` eliding? Or is that literal?

Comment: ...... are just the sql..just like the sql table color mentioned above

Comment: Does `prep.sh` exit with an error code of `2` in some place?